# How to use List<Double> in RealmObject model class

Tags: android, realm

In my Android project , I have model class as below

```
public class PilotMovement extends RealmObject {

private String type;
private RealmList<Coordinates> coordinates;

public PilotMovement() {
}

public PilotMovement(String type, RealmList<Coordinates> coordinates) {
    this.type = type;
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setCoordinates(RealmList<Coordinates> coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

public class Coordinates extends RealmObject{
private double lon, lat;
public Coordinates(double lon, double lat) {
    this.lon = lon;
    this.lat = lat;
}
}
```

---

Custom GSON Type adapter for RealmList as below

```
public class CoordinatesRealmListConverter implements
    JsonSerializer<RealmList<Coordinates>>,
    JsonDeserializer<RealmList<Coordinates>> {
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(RealmList<Coordinates> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for (Coordinates coordinates: src) {
        jsonArray.add(context.serialize(coordinates));
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
@Override
public RealmList<Coordinates> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    RealmList<Coordinates> coordinates = new RealmList<>();
    JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
    for (JsonElement element: jsonArray) {
       coordinates.add(context.deserialize(element,Coordinates.class));
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

After running project showing compile error as below

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.

> com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported type java.lang.Object

What is the solution how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using RealmList instead of list. But as I remember Realm is not supporting lists of non-RealmObjects. So, the best way is to separate coordinates to something like that:

```
public class LocationInfo extends RealmObject {
    private String type;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
}
```

Comment: This is good but i have to pass this data to server it expects the same as LIst<Double> type.

Comment: It's not a problem. Just configure your JSON serializator to format an appropriate json from this pojo

Comment: Do you mean like this 
    new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, LocationInfo.class);
Can I have an example snippet please.

Comment: You can find snippets in docs of the library you are using. Here are some for GSON library, for example: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: I have updated my question please check and give me a solution.